# Get field value from referenced entity in twig loop

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have a content type with a multiple referenced field and I need to iterate trough each item and display the item information in a table but I don't know and didn't find a way to access the content field information like the value of a specific field.

Example:
I have a content type called Task and in Task I have multiple Entity Reference to Worker content type, Worker has title, name and phone. How can I iterate each worker and display the information in a table?

What I want to do is to override **node--task.html.twig** to do something like this:

Assuming that we have a field_workers field in task content type.

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>
         Name
       </th>
       <th>
         Phone
       </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    {% for worker in content.field_workers %}
     <tr>
       <td>
        {{worker.field_name.value}}
       </td>
       <td>
         {{worker.field_phone.value}}
       </td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: Just nipping out so can't check, but is `worker.entity` defined in the loop? If so it's probably just a matter of using `{{worker.entity.field_name.value}}` etc

Comment: That did not work. Probably the worker entity is not defined in the loop, can't tell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to work with node instead of content.

something like this should work

```
{% for item in node.field_workers %}
 {{ item.entity.field_name.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

See [Entity API Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/msankhala/d93ca2d0307a122e2df7512a60403c81) and [Twig and Entity Field API or how to take control of node.html.twig](http://www.md-systems.ch/en/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig) (my blog post) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Berdir, this solved my problem! Sorry about my late reply, I was not at work. 
Trying to avoid another question or more search, do you know how may I be able to format dates and access the {{ author_name }} of that item? Thank you.
I also would like to have the quick edit|edit|delete|manage display button in each row of my table, is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

As @Berdir explains in http://www.md-systems.ch/en/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig you have two options, use the `node` entity (see Berdir's answer) or the render array in `content`. For the content approach you have to put the table row in a second node template:

**node--task.html.twig**

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>
         Name
       </th>
       <th>
         Phone
       </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {{ content.field_workers }}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**node--worker--table.html.twig**

```
     <tr>
       <td>
         {{ content.field_name }}
       </td>
       <td>
         {{ content.field_phone }}
       </td>
     </tr>
```

Disadvantage obviously is you need two templates. Advantage is, you can render the Worker fields how they are configured in UI and you can use text filters. Use a separate view mode `table`, so that you can display the Worker content type in other places as normal. You might also need to remove html from the `field--field-workers.html.twig` template if it's in the way of the table structure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and sorry about my late reply. I liked your solution but I could only manage to solve it with Berdir answer. Best regards!

Comment: Building tables in templates can get quite complicated, it might be easier to build a table in Views and attach it to the node with https://www.drupal.org/project/eva

Comment: there was a syntax error in the first template, corrected it

Comment: Yes I noticed that. Thank you for tour suggestion, I think that what I need to do is solved with templates but I will take a look if I need to add complexity!